# Teaching OOP (C++) outside-in vs inside-out approach

Tags: c++, oop

I am running a programming club at a high-school, and I have introduced my students to OOP using simplistic classes in C++. I believe at least theoretically they get the idea. I would like to be able to offer them a specific project they can work on together. The question I have is which approach to take. When I took programming classes in college, I saw two different approaches, but in my opinion they both had serious shortcomings. I ended up sleeping through most of them and learning the stuff on my own from books and examples.
Now that I am in the teacher's shoes, I would like to get your opinion on which approach is preferable or if there is a third option.

Approach 1 that was used, was to write a program on the board (or on a computer with a projection screen). The class definitions were always written first. Usually students would look really bewildered at this point, because the purpose of variables and methods would seem entirely obscure to them. The only time that they learned about what each variable and method was for and how they interacted was when the instructor would finally write the implementation (I called this the outside-in method)

Approach 2 was to explain what we are trying to achieve, and creating classes and members as needed. This has the opposite problem. He would be writing a method that would use these imaginary classes that would have to be implemented later. But the students has no idea how these other classes would work.

Comment: I will be starting teaching OOP in a couple of months... I'm very interested in good input to this question :)

Comment: These are generally known as "top down" and "bottom up" development. Current consensus seems to run toward starting from *both* ends and meeting in the middle, so to speak (but I don't think there's anything approaching complete agreement on one right way to do things).

Comment: I would go for Approach 3. Define classes and flush out methods in the class based on how they are used. The classes needs to be defined first because that would build their OOP design capability, while flushing out methods as the objects are being used will make sure that only the minimum required functions are defined in each class and would give context as to how each class interact with each other.

Comment: Thanks @JerryCoffin for introducing the "top down" and "bottom up" terminology. However, I find your claim that there is any consensus on the matter dubious; I'd like to know what you base your claim on. Regardless, you seem to be making a claim about the right way to do software *development*, whereas this question is about the clearest way to *teach* OOP.

Comment: Whilst I agree that some reference data would be good here, the "Approach 3" feels right to me. How about two screens, one showing the top down and the other showing the bottom up? As calls are made in the top down view, add them to the class interface in the bottom up view. Selectively implement in the bottom up to make concrete the belief that they _can_ be implemented.

Comment: @SchighSchagh: "Consensus" may have been over-stating the situation a bit (though I intended the final parenthetical to imply it was a weak consensus at best). It would probably be more accurate to say that both top-down and bottom-up have had their advocates, but neither has achieved wide-spread consensus, so (at least IME) working from both ends inward seems to end up as the default (primarily for development, but to at least some extent for teaching as well).

Comment: I think this sort of discussion belongs on programmers.se

Answer (score 6):

As it happens, I worked my way through University by working as a teacher.  I am now a software engineer.

In my experience, it is paramount that the students be emotionally invested in a programming project.  I'll get to your question in a minute, this is a necessary preamble.

To get there, I made the topic of the program something that really interested them, regardless of how silly it seemed, as long as it was something that connected with them in their world.

So, it could be (depending on the age of your students) about ranking singing stars by their talent level, including Justin Bieber.  You can imagine the uproar at that one.

Like, Load their lyrics and count the number of times they say the word "baby".  Something creative, something fun.

This will make "dry" questions come alive.  Like, what should the "singer" class look like.  Why it should have properties like "octave range" will be immediately intuitive.

Should the singer class have a method called 'barfOnStage'?  (The Biebs barfed on stage a while ago).  Sure, why not!?  They will easily see the difference between methods and properties.

I mean, I'm just talking off the top of my head, I'm sure you can apply your own inventiveness and creativity to whatever's appropriate for your kids.

I would love to hear what you went with, and how the kids' project turned out.

Answer (score 0):

For the beginner level I would go with a modified number 2 approach where you start with an easy problem and then build on it. Experience is the best teacher....like the time my High School teacher had us 'iterate' through twenty discrete variables as a 'list' and *then* taught us about arrays....

You need to select the right problem. It needs to be a problem that exercises the 'object oriented muscles' not the 'algorithm muscles'. It needs to be something that you can build requirements on it that exercise object orientation. A simple CRUD program should be adequate. You'll just have to constrain them to using objects and not arrays as I assume they'll be comfortable doing. I'll leave the exact specification up to you.

**First**, have them write a program that just lets them add records to the 'database'. Just by Creating a 'row' in their 'database' they'll be forced to learn how to create an object and instantiate an object.

**Next**, have them modify their program to display the contents of their 'database'. When they Read their 'database' they'll exercise the .show function or however you implement that capability.

**Third**, have them make it so they can change the contents of a 'record'. Updating will reinforce how to tell an object to modify itself.

**Finally**, they should modify the program to allow for 'record' removal. This will reinforce proper object destruction.

Taking it to the next level (and since this is c++) you could:

- require they implement their 'database' as a linked list
- write the specification so you can do something that requires objects
  being added together
- add to the scope of data so the program structure would be better
  facilitated by a template or inheritance (vehicle 'database' that has
  both cars and motorcycles for example)

From my experience doing is the best teacher. Having someone show me how to do something (or doing it as a group on a board) short circuits the learning. Wrestling with it and having some Socratic guidance teaches a deeper understanding and yields a better programming brain.

If they aren't ready to do the 'create' function then coding it out as a group on the whiteboard will work, but once they have a template of how everything fits together they need to be behind a computer figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a beginner programming course I'd say the OOP aspect is of minor issue. Focus on expressions, statements and control flow.

If the focus is on OOP I'd say begin with the history of OOP and what OOP focus is. From that one can look at how one describe these concepts in different languages. (i.e. ADT, Simula etc http://retis.sssup.it/~lipari/courses/oosd2010-1/02.oop.pdf )

...and then experiment.

> *"If we look at the whole history, we see that the proto-OOP stuff started with ADT, ..."*
>   -- Alan Kay (http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/~ram/pub/pub_jf47ht81Ht/doc_kay_oop_en)